# Algorithm used in Ruby for "String#include?"

Tags: ruby, algorithm, search, substring

Is anyone able to pinpoint which algorithm is used for the include? method in Ruby? For example

```
"helloworld".include?("hello")
```

Comment: You know you can look at [the source](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/include%3F), right? (Then look at the C source, at least for String's include.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As *emboss* states in his answer, `String#include` calls `rb_str_index`. This function in turn calls `rb_memsearch`, which implements the  [Rabin-Karp string search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_string_search_algorithm), according to [this post](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/87830) on `ruby-forum.com`.

Comment: Does the `string[substr]` call the same functions for search? I mean *the same algorithm, the same speed*.

Answer (score 7):

The Ruby Language Specification doesn't prescribe any particular algorithm. Every implementation can use whatever algorithm they want.

For example, in [Rubinius](http://Rubini.us/), [`String#include?`](https://GitHub.Com/Rubinius/Rubinius/blob/master/kernel/common/string.rb#L998-1007) calls `String#find_string`:

```
def include?(needle)
  if needle.kind_of? Fixnum
    needle = needle % 256
    str_needle = needle.chr
  else
    str_needle = StringValue(needle)
  end

  !!find_string(str_needle, 0)
end
```

[`String#find_string`](https://GitHub.Com/Rubinius/Rubinius/blob/master/kernel/bootstrap/string.rb#L56-59) in turn is implemented via the `string_index` primitive:

```
def find_string(pattern, start)
  Rubinius.primitive :string_index
  raise PrimitiveFailure, "String#find_string failed"
end
```

The [`string_index`](https://GitHub.Com/Rubinius/Rubinius/blob/master/vm/builtin/string.hpp#L171-172) primitive is implemented by the `rubinius::String::index` function:

```
// Rubinius.primitive :string_index
Fixnum* index(STATE, String* pattern, Fixnum* start);
```

[`rubinius::String::index`](https://GitHub.Com/Rubinius/Rubinius/blob/master/vm/builtin/string.cpp#L1018-1060):

```
Fixnum* String::index(STATE, String* pattern, Fixnum* start) {
  native_int total = size();
  native_int match_size = pattern->size();

  if(start->to_native() < 0) {
    Exception::argument_error(state, "negative start given");
  }

  switch(match_size) {
  case 0:
    return start;
  case 1:
    {
      uint8_t* buf = byte_address();
      uint8_t matcher = pattern->byte_address()[0];

      for(native_int pos = start->to_native(); pos < total; pos++) {
        if(buf[pos] == matcher) return Fixnum::from(pos);
      }
    }
    return nil<Fixnum>();
  default:
    {
      uint8_t* buf = byte_address();
      uint8_t* matcher = pattern->byte_address();

      uint8_t* last = buf + (total - match_size);
      uint8_t* pos = buf + start->to_native();

      while(pos <= last) {
        // Checking *pos directly then also checking memcmp is an
        // optimization. It's about 10x faster than just calling memcmp
        // everytime.
        if(*pos == *matcher &&
            memcmp(pos, matcher, match_size) == 0) {
          return Fixnum::from(pos - buf);
        }
        pos++;
      }
    }
    return nil<Fixnum>();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is the actual implementation of `String#include?`:

```
static VALUE
rb_str_include(VALUE str, VALUE arg)
{
    long i;

    StringValue(arg);
    i = rb_str_index(str, arg, 0);

    if (i == -1) return Qfalse;
    return Qtrue;
}
```

So the actual algorithm used can be found in [rb_str_index](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/string.c#L2398).

Comment: Which in turn uses `rb_memsearch`, which implements the [Karp Rabin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_string_search_algorithm) algorithm (according to [this post](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/87830)).

Comment: @rdvdijk: I'd make this an answer :-)

Comment: @rdvdijk Nice one. You should answer this. I will delete my answer then.

Comment: No need to delete! I'll reference your answer.